# Finding the domain and range of prime number

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The question is

In prime number theory the following notation  is  used:

- $P_r$ is the $r$th  prime number;
- $\pi(r)$ is the number of prime numbers less than or equal to $r$.

For each  of  these functions, state

(a) the domain,

(b)  the values for $1\le r \le10$

(c) the range.

How do I solve this problem? Hints, suggestions needed.

Comment: The domain of $P_r$ is $\Bbb N$ the natural numbers.  The domain of $\pi(r)$ is $\Bbb R$ the set of all real numbers.  Or you could restrict $\pi$ to $[1,\infty)$ because it's zero to the left of $1$.

Comment: No it can only be equal to a whole number, but the domain is not what comes out of the function it's what goes in.  Any real number can go in,

Comment: I get it, thanks, @GregoryGrant!

Comment: Actually $\pi$ is zero to the left of two so you could also restrict to $[2,\infty)$.  The graph of $\pi$ is of a step function, it's horizontal between primes then takes a step up of one at each prime.

Comment: @GregoryGrant i get the domain part. how do i find the values in the given interval and the range?

Comment: The range is what comes out of the functions.  Obviously what comes out of $P_r$ is exactly the set of primes themselves and what comes out of $\pi$ is less obvious, it actually depends on whether or not there are infinitely many primes.  If for example there were only $62$ different primes then the range of $\pi$ would be $\{1,2,3,\dots,62\}$ and once it hit $62$ it would stay there forever.  BUT in reality there are infinitely many primes.  So how does that change the answer?

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. It would make sense if it would ask for the maximal domain such that this function is well-defined.

Comment: @Math_QED I was just about to make a comment like that ... how can we know what the domain is if we are not given some *initial* restriction of what objects could *potentially* be in the domain?  I mean, I could define a class of objects $\mathbb{N} \cup \{ bananas \}$ and define some kind of 'less than' relationship on all those objects (say, for any $n \in \mathbb{N}: n < bananas)$, and now $bananas$ would suddenly be part of the domain of the $\pi$ function. So, again, you really need to know some kind of initial restriction on the *kinds* of objects we're talking about in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer questions like this, you look up the definitions of the domain and range of a function.  The domain is the set of things you can apply the function to, and the range is the set of values it can take.  Clearly the domain of $P_r$ is the natural numbers (not including zero) and the range is the set of primes.  $\pi(r)$ could have a domain of the naturals or the reals.  Its range is the naturals including zero.  For b, simply apply the function to $1,2,3,\ldots 10$ and report the results.

Comment: Yeah, i got the solution for prime number. i understood the mapping from 1,2... 10 to the prime numbers. But I'm having difficulty in second part. How do I find values for $pi(r)$ between 0 to 10, and the range of $pi(r)$. The given answer in book for b) is $0,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4$. For range, $\Bbb N \bigcup {0}$

Comment: You just count the primes.  The smallest primes are $2,3,5,7$ so all those fours at the end are counting all of them.

Comment: Aaah, got it. But I had to exclude 0 from range of $pi(r)$ to get the result. So the range of $pi(r)$ is natural numbers, right. What does $\Bbb N \cup 0$ mean though?

Comment: The range of $\pi(r)$ should include $0$ because $\pi(1)=0$.  $\Bbb N \cup 0$ is used for zero plus all the naturals by people who think zero does not belong to $\Bbb N$.  Whether it does is a matter of definition and varies, mostly by field of study.

Comment: For b) I'm having 11 elements in range, and 10 elements in domain, which are natural numbers. How to map them? Even for prime part, I'm mapping upto number 29 only in range, whereas answer has 11 prime numbers, i.e.., till 31. Where am i wrong?

Comment: For b you are asking about $\pi (r)$ for $r=1,2,3,\ldots 10$.  The values are $2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29$  No, $31$ should not be included as it is $\pi (11)$  The range of a function never has more elements in it than there are in the domain.

Comment: ok, got it. Understood clearly. Many thanks to you.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that these notations all mean different things.  Most of the texts I use are common for undergrad to graduate level mathematics.  Understand that a century of studies have yielded fairly complete answers in the past and there is a great quantity of information already available about prime numbers, and so I would contribute this.

---

### A Few Notations for Prime Numbers

- $p,q \in \mathbb{P}$ or $P$, would indicate $p$ and $q$ are [prime numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number).
- $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$ would indicate $m$ and $n$ are integers.
- $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ (sometimes $\mathbb{N}$) would indicate $m$ and $n$ are positive.
- $\mathbb{Z} \cap [2,+\infty)$ would indicate the set of positive integers greater than $1$
- $(\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z})$ would be the set of residue classes $\{a \mod q\}$
- $(\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z})^*$ would be the set of residue classes $\{a \mod q\}$ where $a$ and $q$ are coprime -- that their greatest common factor was 1.
- [Modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) means that the numbers are tied together in loops of constant length. (i.e. $+_q$, $*_q$ would be modular addition and multiplication.  see Warner, Modern Algebra.)
- $p_i$ would be used where $p$ was a sequence.
- Note that $\bigcup [x+1]^+_{(x+1)}$ indicates the set of positive composite numbers if this was the union of the arithmetic progressions with infimum of $a + q$
- Then the primes are $\mathbb{Z}^+ \setminus \bigcup [x+1]^+_{(x+1)}$, where $\setminus$ is setwise subtraction.  The [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) arrives in the following form, for the sequence of prime numbers:
  $$ p_{i+1} = \inf\{ [2,\infty) \setminus \bigcup_{0 < k \le i} [0]_{p_k} \} $$
- If $i = 0$ then $\bigcup_{0 < k \le i} [0]_{p_k} := \emptyset $, the empty set, so that $p_1 = 2$, $p_2 = 3$...
- $\pi(x)$ being the stepwise prime counting function, it can be roughly approximated by $Li(x)\sim \frac{x}{\log x}+ O(\frac{x}{\log^2 x})$ or $\int \frac{dx}{\log x} + O(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}})$ when $x \rightarrow +\infty$ with the Prime Number Theorem and bounds implied by Riemann Hypothesis.
- Both $\pi(x)$ and $p_i$ are contained by the [Baire Space (Set Theory)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_space_(set_theory)) since they were both functions from $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$.

  Li$(x)$ is a real valued function, uniformly continuous for $(1, +\infty)$ and continuous for $[1, +\infty)$